# How to call a DAO method from a Json Servlet

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a dependency dropdown list in my JSP. I have a json servlet where I populate the second dropdown. Based on the selection made for the first dropdown will determine the second dropdown. I have hardcoded values within the jsonServlet class but I want to be able to call a query from my DAO method. How would I go about this?

JsonServlet:

```
package master.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import master.dao.MasterDataDao;
import master.dto.SiteDto;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class JsonServlet
 * @param <E>
*/
public class JsonServlet<E> extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    MasterDataDao masterDataDao = new MasterDataDao();
    String divisionIdName = request.getParameter("divisionIdName");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<SiteDto> site = new ArrayList<SiteDto>();
        String json = null;

        if (divisionIdName.equals("33") || divisionIdName.equals("36")) {
            try {
                site.equals(masterDataDao.getAllJJSites());
                for (Iterator<SiteDto> iter = site.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){
                    SiteDto element = iter.next();
                    list.addAll(-1, element);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (Iterator<SiteDto> iter = site.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){
                SiteDto element = iter.next();

            }
        } else if (divisionIdName.equals("Select Division")) {
                list.add("Select Site");

        } else {
            try {
                site.equals(masterDataDao.getAllSites());
                for (Iterator<SiteDto> iter = site.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){
                    SiteDto element = iter.next();
                    list.addAll(-1, element);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

}

Based off the divisionID selection in my JsonServlet, if the divisionID is either 33 or 36 i'd like to call this method in my MasterDataDao class:

```
 public List<SiteDto> getAllJJSites() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<SiteDto> siteDtoList = new ArrayList<SiteDto>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String query = "Select Distinct Name, Id  From Addtl_Type Where Addtl_Type.is_active = '1' And Data_Field_Id = 3050 Order By Name";
        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // System.out.println("&*******" + rs.getFetchSize());
        while (rs.next()) {
            SiteDto siteDto = new SiteDto();
            siteDto.setId(rs.getString("Id"));
            siteDto.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
            siteDtoList.add(siteDto);
        }
    } finally {

        cleanUp(con, ps, rs);
    }
    return siteDtoList;
}
```

Otherwise if it is another selection value(besides Select Division), I'd like to call this method with the MasterDataDao class:

```
 public List<SiteDto> getAllSites() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<SiteDto> siteDtoList = new ArrayList<SiteDto>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String query = "Select Distinct Name, Id  From Addtl_Type Where Addtl_Type.is_active = '1' And Data_Field_Id = 105 Order By Name";
        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // System.out.println("&*******" + rs.getFetchSize());
        while (rs.next()) {
            SiteDto siteDto = new SiteDto();
            siteDto.setId(rs.getString("Id"));
            siteDto.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
            siteDtoList.add(siteDto);
        }
    } finally {

        cleanUp(con, ps, rs);
    }
    return siteDtoList;
}
```

Is this possible to do within the JsonServlet? If so how? Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if more information is needed.

Also I have included my JSP here. Initially I had made a call to the DAO from here. I referenced a bean. 
JSP:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#divisionId').change(function(event) {
        var divisionId = $("select#divisionId").val();
        $.get('JsonServlet', {
            divisionIdName : divisionId
        }, function(response) {

            var select = $('#siteId');
            select.find('option').remove();
            $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>


 </head>
 <body>

<form name="input" action="getMasterData" method="get">



    <br /> <br />
    <h1 align='center'>Master Data File</h1>
    <br /> <br />


    <table border="0" align='center'>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Division</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'><jsp:useBean id="masterDaoUtil"
                    class="master.dao.util.MasterDataConstants" /> 
                    <select name="divisionId" id="divisionId">
                    <option>Select Division</option>
                    <option value="33">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_AUDIT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="31">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_CHANGE_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="34">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_DEA_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="35">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EHS_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="23">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="36">
 \
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_QUALITY_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="40">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_AUDIT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="43">


<%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_CHANGE_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="41">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_DEA_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="42">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_EHS_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
                    <option value="44">
 <%=MasterDataConstants.DIVISION_TYPE_NORAMCO_EVENT_MANAGEMENT_GLOBAL_NAME%></option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Site Name</h2>
            </td>
            <td align='left'>
 <%--               <jsp:useBean id="masterDao"
                    class="master.dao.MasterDataDao" /> 
 --%>                       
                    <select name="siteId"
                id="siteId">
                    <option>Select Site</option>
 <%--                   <option value="0">ALL</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${masterDao.allSites}" var="siteDto">
                        <option value="${siteDto.id}">${siteDto.name}
 </option>
                    </c:forEach>
 --%>                           
            </select></td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <br /> <br />
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>
<%
    if (request.getAttribute("message") != null) {
%>
<p>
    <font size=4 color="red"> Master_Data(timestamp).xlsx and
        Consistency_Check_Data(timestamp).xlsx are located under
        d:/stage/MasterDataReports <%--Master_Data(timestamp).xlsx and Consistency_Check_Data(timestamp).xlsx are located under /jsc/ets/u02/tools7/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/MasterData/MasterDataReport--%>
    </font>
</p>
<%
    }
%>
```

Originally before I used JSON and AJAX I used this statement for the options which is now commented out.

```
  <%--               <jsp:useBean id="masterDao"
                class="master.dao.MasterDataDao" /> 
  --%>                       
                <select name="siteId"
            id="siteId">
                <option>Select Site</option>
  <%--                   <option value="0">ALL</option>
                <c:forEach items="${masterDao.allSites}" var="siteDto">
                    <option value="${siteDto.id}">${siteDto.name}
```

Is there a way I can leverage this? Maybe can I make a function call to the JSP from my servlet? I know this is not good practice but I cannot think of another way. I need to get the siteDto.id value as well as the siteDto.name value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing when you create an instance of the desired class and then invoke the desired method on it? This is just basic Java and does absolutely not depend on whatever the class/method is in turn doing and also not what the caller is doing. This has basically got nothing to do with JSON/Ajax/JSP/Servlets.

Comment: Hi BalusC. I tried directly calling the DAO methods within my servlet but it wanted me to change my method to a static method. This would cause issues since I have connection calls within that method that would also have to be changed

Comment: So you didn't create an instance of it? What exactly is preventing you from creating an instance of it?

Comment: Let me try that now. I was thinking more complicated. Thanks for the advice. Also I wanted to point out that I have two servlets. Does it make sense to have 2 servlets? I just thought I needed 2 because the JSON servlet needed to stand on its own.

Comment: Hi BalusC, So I have taken your advice and created an instance of the class MasterDataDao and inserted the correct query calls within the if else statements. Now my java skills are far from par. What is the best way to iterate through the list and display the values? I have updated my JsonServlet code with the changes above. I am having an issue with list.add vs list.addAll. Thanks again in advance

Comment: @BalusC  I have now added my JSP code and show how I was initially making my option calls before using JSON. it is commented out now. Is there a way I can leverage this? Please take a peak at my JSP above.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface and implementation `DAO` like `IMasterDataDAO` and `MasterDataDAOImpl`.

In case if you get more `if..else` condition in future then use switch..case instead of `if..else`.

Create an object for `DAO` using the interface in `servlet` like below:

```
IMasterDataDAO masterDAO = new MasterDataDAOImpl()
```

then call either `masterDAO.getAllJSites()` or `masterDAO.getAllSites()` based on the condition.

Comment: hello Zayn and Prasanna. Thanks for your response. I have  created both the interface and the implementation file as you have stated above. How would I go about iterating thought the Result set and populating the dropdowns now? I've written something like this:                                          
    if (divisionIdName.equals("33") || divisionIdName.equals("36")) {
   
   list.add("Select Site");
   list.add(0, "ALL");
   for (ListIterator<SiteDto> iter = jj_site.listIterator(); iter
     .hasNext();) {
    list.add(siteDtoList.getId());
    // String element = iter.next();
   }

Comment: Hi prasanna. I have now added my JSP code and show how I was initially making my option calls before using JSON. it is commented out now. Is there a way I can leverage this? Please take a peak at my JSP above. –